# How to start activity with two buttons

Tags: android, button

How do I write a code so that when you press the first button (btn1) and then the second button (btn2), does the second activity(SecondActivity) start?

Comment: disable/enable second button based on first button click in OnClickLitsener of first button.

Comment: disable second button initially and make it enable after first is clicked . Whats so tricky here??

Comment: I am a beginner. How do I do that?

Comment: btn1 + btn2 = SecondActivity                                                                                            btn1 = nothing                                                                                                                  btn2 = nothing                                                                                                                    btn2 + btn1 = nothing

Comment: @ADM Button 2 fired only after clicking on button 1.

Comment: How do I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

Boolean launch = false;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button btn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    Button btn2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);

    btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            launch = true;
        }
    });

    btn2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (launch == true)
            {
                Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Main2Activity.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
            else
            {
                //do your stuff
            }
        }
    });
}
}
```